# Docker containers linking

Tags: docker, dns

I have an nginx routing to two app containers.

I have a login application running in one of the containers - account.myproduct.local

My other application is running in other container - 
calendar.myproduct.local

If a request is made to calendar.practo.local it makes an Openid auth redirect to account.myproduct.local

**Problem:**
I have linked the containers but since account.myproduct.local is not resolvable from calendar container(calendar.myproduct.local), login is not happening.
How should i make it resolvable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link command to add an alias to the /etc/hosts of calendar.myproduct.local. Your link on calendar would be like this:

`--link account_container_name:account.myproduct.local`

This way calendar.myproduct.local will be able to resolve the hostname account.myproduct.local without having to know its IP.

Comment: account.myproduct.local is resolved via proxing through nginx container. Should i link nginx in this case then, will it work?                                                                      `--link nginx:account.myproduct.local`. Also i heard with docker1.9 links have been deprecated and docker has its own network which should be used. How to use that?

Comment: Adding links with dot in it doesnt work ! services.calendar.links contains an invalid type, it should be a string
services.accounts.links contains an invalid type, it should be a string

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
With docker version `1.10` and above. There is no need to link containers as docker-compose makes a default network and all the services are discoverable by the container name. Changing the service name to the nginx server name solved the problem for me.

Now accounts.myproduct.local and calendar.myproduct.local are resolvable from outside(`coz of the /etc/hosts in my mac`) and also resolvable internally for communication(`using the service name which is resolvable in the same network`)

**Detail with proper example:** https://github.com/alok87/dockerex

New docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
   accounts.myproduct.local:
     build: accounts

   calendar.myproduct.local:
     build: calendar

   router:
     build: router
     ports:
     - 80:80
```